# Typecast Object type to user defined POJO in java

Tags: java

Consider an example

```
public Object myMethod()
{
     //some condition
     return obj of type Object1;
     //else
     return obj of type Object2;

}
```

I call it as follows,

```
Object obj = myMethod();

obj = (obj instanceof Object1)? (Object1)obj : (Object2) obj;
```

My problem is even after typecasting obj is neither of type Object1 nor of type Object2. What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Please provide further code i.e. what you want to do after getting the object of type1 or type2 in obj. And also your last line of code is of no use(it does not make any change).

Comment: If you give these objects the same parent interface, it will make it simpler to work with both types without duplicating your code.

Answer (score 3):

There's no point in casting without assigning to a variable of the type you are casting to, so you'll need two variables.

```
Object obj = myMethod();
Object1 obj1 = null;
Object2 obj2 = null;
if (obj instanceof Object1) {
    obj1 = (Object1) obj;
    // some specific Object1 handling
} else if (obj instanceof Object2) {
    obj2 = (Object2) obj;
    // some specific Object2 handling
}
```

Comment: Thing is I have to use the same variable obj from there onwards otherwise I may have to write separate codes for obj1 and obj2.

Comment: @SurajHK If your code needs to use specific methods of Object1 or Object2, you must have references to both of them, and your code would be different for each type returned by the myMethod. If the rest of your code should look the same, regardless of the type returned by `myMethod` (i.e. it will call only methods that exist both in Object1 and Object2), you should define an interface containing all the methods that Object1 and Object2 share, and cast obj to this interface.

Answer (score 1):

The object you are casting is already the correct type. Your cast after the call to `myMethod` is useless.

You need to assign the cast object to a reference of the same type in order to use it.

```
Object obj = myMethod();
if( obj instanceof Object1 ){
   doSomething((Object1) obj);
} else {
   doSomething((Object2) obj);
}
```

You can then use the correct interface in your overloaded `doSometing` methods.